# Hashmap NoSuchElementException error

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap, hashset

I've been struggling with an java.util.NoSuchElementException error when I execute printAll.

```
public class myDatabase {

    Map<String, HashSet<Integer>> mapOfSets = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>();

    void printAll() {

        if (mapOfSets.isEmpty() == false)
        {
                for (String key : mapOfSets.keySet()) 
                {
                    System.out.println(key);

                    //print the set
                    for (HashSet<Integer> id : mapOfSets.values() ) 
                        System.out.println(id);
                }
        }

}
```

//rest of empty code...

**Update from comments: The exception is**

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException 
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:809) 
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:841) 
at StudentDatabase.report(myDatabase.java:29) 
at DatabaseRun1.main(DatabaseRun1.java:52)
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? And why you're you using `mapOfSets.get(key)`?

Comment: Not an answer but an observation. You can use `if(boolean)`. So you can also (and should) write `if (!mapOfSets.isEmpty())`

Comment: I just wanted to print the each key once along with the value of that key (being a set) under it. I execute the function printAll in another class and my compiler sends me to the "void printAll() {" line.

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean, he is *not* using `mapOfSets.get(key)`, right? IMHO, none of the methods he is calling can throw a NSEE exception

Comment: Yep, code as shown definitely doesn't throw the stated exception. @Altermax - include your full stack trace.

Comment: @Altermax. Instead of `mapOfSets.values()` you need to use `mapOfSets.get(key)` as already specified in above comments. The first method gets you all the List of all the values. And not the value for that key. Also, can you post your Stack Trace of Exception please?

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, that's what I meant. I can't type, apparently.

Comment: And you definitely don't need to do that test - `mapOfSets.isEmpty() == false`.

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:809)
 at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:841)
 at StudentDatabase.report(myDatabase.java:29)
 at DatabaseRun1.main(DatabaseRun1.java:52) ("void printAll() {" line) I call it in a class called DatabaseRun1

Comment: I suspect the exception is thrown because of the code you haven't shown at all. The code you have posted cannot throw this exception.

Comment: @Altermax You should add such comments to the question - I did it for you this time :) As @Rohit says, the code you posted seems to be different from what causes the exception. There is no `printAll()` method in the stack trace. Please show some code around `StudentDatabase.report(myDatabase.java:29)`

Comment: And as per naming conventions, your class should be named `MyDatabase` instead of `myDatabase`

Comment: This exception is not being thrown by this code, as the stack trace makes clear. -1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you'd be better off using `entrySet`

```
for(Map.Entry<String, HashSet<Integer>> entry : mapOfSets.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    HashSet<Integer> value = entry.getValue();

    // Print it
}
```

I don't see how this code could produce a `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: It's true. It's not my function, because when I empty the function the exception still runs.Thanks for your time

Comment: I hade to make a new project, then put everything in again, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
                for (HashSet<Integer> id : mapOfSets.values() ) 
                    System.out.println(id);
```

to

```
      for (Integer i : mapOfSets.get(key)) {
        System.out.println(i);
      }
```

or (as @JonSkeet points out)

```
       System.out.println(mapOfSets.get(key));
```

Essentially, you are trying to print the map instead of the set inside the map at the key location.

Comment: I'd expect `HashSet` to print out the right thing already. Just `System.out.println(mapOfSets.get(key))` should be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Good call - but asker seemed to want to print newlines between each - very confusing.

Comment: In that case, I'd stick with an enhanced `for` loop: `for (Integer id : mapOfSets.get(key)) { System.out.println(id); }` - there's no reason to avoid the enhanced for loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet - good point - fixed.